# Updating text live with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been doing a project with jQuery recently and I have hit an issue. The basic idea is to create some JS code so that as you enter content into a text box on a tab, the text inside a div changes as you type, and when you move to a new tab it changes to the text inside the text box there. It is quite hard to explain so there is a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/bNnpT/

**EDIT:**
Apologies, I was quite unclear in my question. I have the modal working fine, my problem is as follows: When a user creates a tab they are presented with three text boxes. As they enter text into the text boxes on one tab the text inside  updates live with what they entered into Title, Subtitle and Content, similar to how text entered into the "Page Title" text box renames the tab live. When the user changes tab, the text should update to what is in the text boxes in the currently active tab.

What I have Tried:

```
$(".modal-body #pageTitle").html('<h1>' + pageTitle + '</h1>');
$(".modal-body #pageSubtitle").html('<h2>' + pageSubtitle + '</h2>');
$(".modal-body #pageContent").html('<p>' + pageContent + '</p>');
```

Comment: You are trying to reflect the dynamic content in the iPhone frame, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: An updated fiddle with your enhancements provided. :)
This assumes you aren't changing your naming conventions on your elements' ids.

```
// Newly added code.
// Automatically update the iphone display when 
// the user types.
$('#tabContent').on('keyup', 'input[id^="page"], textarea[id^="page"]', function () {
    var _thisId = $(this).attr('id');

    // Parse out the section from the id: (e.g. Title from pageTitle_tab1)
    // and lowercase it to match the naming conventions in this document.
    _thisId = _thisId.substring(4, _thisId.indexOf('_')).toLowerCase();

    // Only 1 preview element so just modify it's html.
    // _thisId will be title|subtitle|content
    $('#' + _thisId + 'Preview').html('<h1>' + $(this).val() + '</h1>');
});

// Generic handler for all tabs, except the first "add tab"
$('#tabHeaders').on('click', 'li:not(:first-child)', function () {
    var index = $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('#tab')[1];

    // index is the tab number, grab our iphone divs and
    // iterate through each one.
    $('div#iphone-frame div[id$="Preview"]').each(function (idx, el) {
        // The next two lines determine which #page[text field]_tab[index]
        // input to grab our text value from.
        var whichId = $(this).attr('id').split('Preview')[0];
        whichId = whichId.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + whichId.slice(1);

        // Get the text value and set it to the corresponding iphone display.
        var textVal = $('#page' + whichId + '_tab' + index).val();
        $(this).html('<h1>' + textVal + '</h1>');
    });
});
// End newly added code
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7S5P/31/

This way you wont need the logic to change the "iphone" values when opening the preview as they are updated on the fly while the user types.

Comment: You sir, went above and beyond. Thanks +1

Comment: There is one small issue with what you have done though. I am using bootstrap-WYSIHTML5 for the content box. When a user types into the content box it does not update live, but rather updates when a user clicks to a new tab then clicks back. Any ideas for a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".modal-body").find("#pageTitle").html('<h1>' + pageTitle + '</h1>');
$(".modal-body").find("#pageSubtitle").html('<h2>' + pageSubtitle + '</h2>');
$(".modal-body").find("#pageContent").html('<p>' + pageContent + '</p>');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bNnpT/3/)**

Comment: Apologies, I was quite unclear in my question. I have the modal working fine, my problem is as follows: When a user creates a tab they are presented with three text boxes. As they enter text into the text boxes on one tab the text inside <div id="iframe-iphone"> updates live with what they entered into Title, Subtitle and Content, similar to how text entered into the "Page Title" text box renames the tab live. When the user changes tab, the text should update to what is in the text boxes in the currently active tab.

Answer (score 0):

If pageTitle (etcetera) is the ID of the element you want to write at:

```
$("#pageTitle").html('<h1>' + pageTitle + '</h1>');
$("#pageSubtitle").html('<h2>' + pageSubtitle + '</h2>');
$("#pageContent").html('<p>' + pageContent + '</p>');
```

Btw: This assumes that before this, you capture the wanted value and put it in the variables pageTitle (etcetera).

Comment: Apologies, I was quite unclear in my question. I have the modal working fine, my problem is as follows:

When a user creates a tab they are presented with three text boxes. As they enter text into the text boxes on one tab the text inside `<div id="iframe-iphone">` updates live with what they entered into Title, Subtitle and Content, similar to how text entered into the "Page Title" text box renames the tab live. When the user changes tab, the text should update to what is in the text boxes in the currently active tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function of jQuery

```
$('.target').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

For your problem it would be something like this:

```
$('.modal-body #pageTitle').change(function() {
    $(select the element where the content needs to be updated).html(<h1>+$('.modal-body #pageTitle').text()+</h1>);
});
```