# Update content editable span text to a tag inner html dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969013/updating-text-live-with-jquery)

I have been doing a project with jQuery and i need a live updating text on all buttons with a class name. I have the editable div but i can't understand how to update the button with editable span,s text. I also want to update other editable spans when user click one span and edit that.


in duplicate question they played with textarea i don't want to play with textarea i want to apply spans text to other editable spans and buttons.


I Am in learning process so it,s quite hard to explain for me and here is my codes

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: none;
    
}
body {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.button {
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #F44336;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:active {
    background-color: #CD3227;
    
}
.code {
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    
}
.btn-text {
 color: #FFF;
}
.sign {
 color: #c5c8c6;
}
.html-tag-inside {
 color: #c82829;
}
.attribute {
 color: #81a2be;
}
.equal {
 color: #3F51B5;
}
.quotation-mark {
 color: #E91E63;
}
.class-and-id-attribute {
 color: #DABA5A;
}
.slash {
 color: #549757;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <a class="btn">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="code">
    <span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a </span><span class="attribute">class</span><span class="equal">&#61;</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="class-and-id-attribute">Btn1</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span><span class="btn-text" contenteditable="true">Button</span><span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="slash">&#47;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <a class="btn">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="code">
    <span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a </span><span class="attribute">class</span><span class="equal">&#61;</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="class-and-id-attribute">Btn2</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span><span class="btn-text" contenteditable="true">Button</span><span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="slash">&#47;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span>
</div>
```

codes on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkjzfypz/)

Comment: try to change at keypress event  of span tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added an `keyup` event handler.

```js
$('[contenteditable]').on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).closest('.code').prev().find('a').html($(this).html());
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: none;
    
}
body {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.button {
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #F44336;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:active {
    background-color: #CD3227;
    
}
.code {
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    
}
.btn-text {
 color: #FFF;
}
.sign {
 color: #c5c8c6;
}
.html-tag-inside {
 color: #c82829;
}
.attribute {
 color: #81a2be;
}
.equal {
 color: #3F51B5;
}
.quotation-mark {
 color: #E91E63;
}
.class-and-id-attribute {
 color: #DABA5A;
}
.slash {
 color: #549757;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
    <a class="btn">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="code">
    <span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a </span><span class="attribute">class</span><span class="equal">&#61;</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="class-and-id-attribute">Btn1</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span><span class="btn-text" contenteditable="true">Button</span><span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="slash">&#47;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <a class="btn">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="code">
    <span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a </span><span class="attribute">class</span><span class="equal">&#61;</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="class-and-id-attribute">Btn2</span><span class="quotation-mark">&#34;</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span><span class="btn-text" contenteditable="true">Button</span><span class="sign">&lt;</span><span class="slash">&#47;</span><span class="html-tag-inside">a</span><span class="sign">&gt;</span>
</div>
```